# Data in not inserted using SQL query

Tags: java

I want to create a Java program which reads lines from a txt file and inserts them one by one using SQL query:

```
    Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\in_progress\\test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    
                List<String> result = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    
                for(String list : result)
                {
                    System.out.println(list);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    ProcessedWords obj = ProcessedWords.builder()
                        .keyword(list)
                        .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .build();
                    processedWordsService.save(obj);
                }
    }
```

I see the lines printed but no SQL query is generated. Do you know where I might be wrong?

Comment: Can you show me a code?

Answer (score 0):

Stream is already used by

```
 stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The `collect` operation is moot. Stream has already been used. You would need to create a new stream at this point.

For instance: in the following, the second operation on stream will throw an exception (`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`):

```
 List<Integer> intList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
 Stream<Integer> integerStream = intList.stream()        

 integerStream.forEach(System.out::println);

 var v = integerStream.collect(Collectors.toList()); // <-- throws exception
```

Are you sure, you do not see this exception in your logs?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Comment: I found another issue: I get infinite loop because value already exists into database.

Comment: There is this error even before. So the program will throw exception and loop will not be even reached

Comment: Can you show me the complete code please?

Comment: Comment out:                 stream.forEach(System.out::println);
And see what happens....